# How to return a string back to a separate class from a method that accepts integers

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm passing two integers to a method in another class, comparing that against a database table, and creating a string for any duplicates found.  I'd like to pass that string back to the calling method/class.

In calling class:

```
if (IsValidMfgBadgeEntries())
    {
        int beginningSerial = Convert.ToInt32(txtMfgBeginning.Text);
        int count = Convert.ToInt32(txtMfgCount.Text);

        SerialsManufacturingDB.VerifyManufacturingSerialOnly
                    (count, beginningSerial);
    }
```

In separate class:

```
public static VerifyManufacturingSerialOnly(int count, int beginning)
    {
        OleDbConnection connection = BadgeDatabaseDB.GetConnection();
        string checkStatement
            = "SELECT OrderNumber "
            + "FROM SerialNumbers-MFG "
            + "WHERE SerialNumber = @CurrentSerial";
        OleDbCommand command =
            new OleDbCommand(checkStatement, connection);

        string duplicateSerials = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                int currentSerial = beginning;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentSerial", currentSerial);                

                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    OleDbDataReader dataReader =
                        command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);
                    if (dataReader.Read())
                    {
                        duplicateSerials +=
                            "Serial # " +
                            currentSerial +
                            " already exists in order # " +
                            dataReader["OrderNumber"].ToString() + "\n";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ;
                    }
                }
                catch (OleDbException ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }

                i++;
            }

            //WHAT TO RETURN??
        }
```

Comment: `public static VerifyManufacturingSerialOnly(int count, int beginning)` is not a valid method declaration, it's missing a return type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must declare the method with a return type (in this case `string`):

```
public static string VerifyManufacturingSerialOnly(int count, int beginning)
```

At the end of the method you can write

```
return duplicateSerials;
```

You can then call the method like this:

```
string result = SerialsManufacturingDB.VerifyManufacturingSerialOnly(count, beginningSerial);
```

---

If you have a method which is not returning a value, you must use the type placeholder `void`

```
public void DoesNotReturnAValue()
{
    ...
}
```

In fact you can use a return statement at any place in the method. A method can have several `return` statements. In a `void` method you simply write

```
return;
```

without argument.

See also

- [return (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/return)
- [Return](https://www.dotnetperls.com/return) with examples at dot net perls.

Comment: that was a simple correction, thanks.  now having difficulty using the return back in the calling method, so may post a question later on that.  thanks.

Comment: Added an example on how to call the method.